# Metric induced by measure $d(A,B) = \mu( A \triangle B)$. Ideal?

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, ideals

Let $d(A,B) = \mu( A \triangle B)$ for content $\mu$ and a ring $R$.

I proved that

$(1)\quad A \sim B \Longleftrightarrow  d(A,B) = 0 $ is a equivalence relation
and

$(2) \quad \mu(A) = \mu(A \cap B) = \mu(B)$.

Now I’m struggling with answer

$(3) \quad$ Is $ [\emptyset ]$ an Ideal in $R$ or at least a Ring?

Any help here is appreciated; thanks.

Comment: At which point of the definition are you stuck?

Comment: @Adayah  to be honest i never worked with Ideals. I looked up the def. of an Ideal and it says that  $0 \in [\emptyset]$ which is not the case here i think? So i only have to check the properties of a Ring ?

Comment: In this ring $0 = \emptyset$, so $0 \in [ \emptyset ]$.

Comment: @Adayah therefore 

$(2) \quad A,B \in [\emptyset] \Rightarrow A-B = 0-0 =0\in [\emptyset]$
 and 

$(3)\quad A \in [\emptyset],B\in R \Rightarrow A \cdot B = 0\cdot B =0 \in [\emptyset] $ if $\mu(B) < \infty ?$

Comment: I see it needs a bit more of a clarification. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify: if $R$ is a ring of sets, then $(R, \Delta, \cap)$ is also a ring (commutative with unity) in the algebraic sense. That's why we can take a subset $I \subseteq R$ and ask whether it is a (ring theoretic) ideal.

For $I$ to be an ideal, it must satisfy the following two properties:

$$\begin{align*}
& \bullet (\forall a, b \in I) \, a+b \in I &&&& (\text{where } + = \Delta) \\[1ex]
& \bullet (\forall r \in R)(\forall a \in I) \, r \cdot a \in I &&&& (\text{where } \cdot = \cap)
\end{align*}$$

We will now check if these hold for $I = [\varnothing] \subseteq R$.

- Let $A, B \in [\varnothing]$. By definition it means that $\mu(A) = \mu(B) = 0$. Then of course $\mu(A \cup B) = 0$, but $A \Delta B \subseteq A \cup B$, hence $\mu(A \Delta B) = 0$, which implies $A \Delta B \in [\varnothing]$.
- Let $A \in [\varnothing]$ and $S \in R$. By definition $\mu(A) = 0$. Since $R \cap A \subseteq A$, we also have $\mu(R \cap A) = 0$, hence $R \cap A \in [\varnothing]$.

This concludes the proof that $I = [\varnothing]$ is an ideal in $R$.

Comment: Thank you now i finally understand how to deal with Ideals.